# Visual studio 2019 preview - auto complete is not selecting the first or any option

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When you use the autocomplete / typeahead, you expect the first option, to be automatically selected, so when you click ENTER, you actually inserting the text.

In VS 2019 you need to click ARROW DOWN and then ENTER.

Any way to change that?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, or choose **Edit** > **IntelliSense** > **Toggle Completion Mode**.

> You can also change to suggestion mode, in which only the text you type is inserted into the code. For example, if you enter an identifier that is not in the list and press Tab, in completion mode the entry would replace the typed identifier. To toggle between completion mode and suggestion mode, press Ctrl+Alt+Space, or choose Edit > IntelliSense > Toggle Completion Mode.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-intellisense?view=vs-2019